# SQL query (join, distinct)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm very new to SQL language. I have two tables, say table1 and table2, table1 has ID and Name columns, table2 has ID and Accounts columns. I need to write a query which shows all the unique names with corresponding account number. Basic example would be:

```
table1         table2

ID Name        ID Accounts
1  foo         1  2
2  bar         2  10
3  baz         3  4
4  foo         4  2
```

Edited: Made up this table myself. The original tables have no input in them.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and the results that you want.

Comment: There is no relationship between the two tables, these tables can not be joined. Are you missing something in your example?

Comment: @MikeEason no, this is exactly the question I have in here, which is why I can't provide an adequate example of it - they all seem irrelevant

Comment: @Kirill You should check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) website if you need more help with SQL language. I know it helped me a lot when I was a beginner.

Comment: @luisarcher Thanks, this is the first site I've come across while learning sql. The question itself seems incredibly inaccurate in every way, so I guess my edited version is what it is supposed to look like. Just have to cut out the duplicates.

Comment: Well, w3schools is not really considered a good ressource. However, where did you get this task from? It doesn't seem to make sense with the two tables given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `left join` and a `distinct` select. So,

```
SELECT DISTINCT  A.Name
                 ,B.Account
     FROM        TableA A
     INNER JOIN  TableB B
                 ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Basically, what this does is that it takes `TableA` and `TableB` commun `ID` and creates rows that now contain an `ID`, a `Name` and an `account number` (you can see it by changing the columns in the select by an `*`). 
Then, the `distinct` removes rows duplicates, which does what youre looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql joining query will be:-**

```
select a.Id,a.Name,b.Id,b.Accounts from table1 a ,table2 where a.Id=b.Id
```

> **joining step1:- choose field name from both tables.**
>
> **joining step2:- compare the base & common field name which will
>   compare data from both tables.**
>
> **a.Id=b.Id will compare the Id from both of tables .**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT table1.Name, table2.Accounts FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID=table2.ID;`

This gives you the `Name` and `Accounts` columns in your resulting table. Because we're using an `INNER JOIN`, we only get records that have matching values in both tables.

You can read more about `JOIN` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that 'foo' is duplicated with a corresponding duplicated accounts value, even though the ID is distinct?  I don't usually trust "distinct" when using more than one column.  While probably unnecessarily complex, I would do:

```
with allnames as (
select
t1.name, 
t2.accounts,
rank() over(partition by t1.name, t2.accounts order by rownum) DUPLICATE_RANK
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
)
select
name, 
accounts
from allnames
where DUPLICATE_RANK = 1
```

That would give you all unique name-account combinations.